# Keep character representation when converting characters from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 encoding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, utf-8, aws-lambda

I am currently working with a 3rd party sports data feed that I call periodically using node to update my database. This feed is `ISO-8859-1` encoded.

My problem is that client devices consuming my data through my APIs, will not be using ISO-8859-1 to display it.

Is there any way to keep the ISO-8859-1 character representation such as áéíóú when I encode to UTF-8 other than mapping the characters I want to replace?

I am running this on AWS lambda and using this [utf8 encoder/decoder npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8)

Thanks!

Comment: áéíóú  cannot keep as is in utf8, or it will be another encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use iconv, the universal solution to encoding switching: https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv

Convert your incoming data to UTF8, when you get it, then store it as UTF8 in your database (and never anything else), and then serve it from that database as UTF8 to your clients.

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up using iconv-lite, but this was definitively what I was looking for !